# Fetch the data from apache lucene index and fill in JTable

Tags: java, swing, loops, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I am trying to search a query from Apache Lucene index.  The search is returning a large amount of result, I have to fill the result in `JTable` using Swing. I am using the loop to extract the object row from Apache Lucene index.

For the above reason if there are thousands of the record  then it takes time to fill the records in table , I am using the following code. Is there any other way to achieve the task without running the loop?

```
  try {         File indexDir= new File("path of the file")

               Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(indexDir);

                    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory, true);
                    int maxhits=1000000;
                    QueryParser parser1 = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, "field",

                      new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36));

              Query qu=parser1.parse("texttosearch");

                    TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(, maxhits);
                    ScoreDoc[] hits = topDocs.scoreDocs;


              len = hits.length;


                     int docId = 0;
                    Document d;
                    Vector column_name=new Vector();   

    column_name.addElement("title"); 
    column_name.addElement(""); 
      // For All Rows Data

    Vector row=new Vector();
     String filename="";
               String titlee="";
    Vector newRow=new Vector();



    for ( i = 0; i<len; i++) {
     docId = hits[i].doc;
     d = searcher.doc(docId);
     filename= d.get(("fpath"));
     titlee=d.get("title");
     newRow= new Vector();
     newRow.addElement(titlee);
     newRow.addElement(filename);
     row.addElement(newRow);                     

    }

    DefaultTableModel model= new DefaultTableModel(row, column_name);
    table.setModel(model);    


 }

catch(Exception ex)

{

  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: *"Is there any other way to achieve the task without running the loop?"*  If there were another way, I doubt it would be faster than the loop.  BTW Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

small mistakes sometimes creates big troubles

- `Vector row = new Vector();` should be `Vector<Vector<Object>> row = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();`
- first line in loop `for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {`  must be `newRow = new Vector();`

pseudo code

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     // must be otherwise first Vector is added forever!!!
     newRow = new Vector();

     //loop, add elements to one dimensional Vector

     // add 1D Vector to 2D Vector used and implemented in JTables API 
     row.addElement(newRow); 
}
```

- I'd be to define variable in form `Vector<Object> newRow = new Vector<Object>();`
- everything important is described in [Oracle turorial How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)